# selecting UISegmentedController segment outside of view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController with layered container views in it, along with this SegmentedController code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dayPicker: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func dayPickerControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch dayPicker.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        monContainer.hidden = false
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 1:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = false
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 2:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = false
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 3:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = false
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 4:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = false
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 5:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = false
        sunContainer.hidden = true
    case 6:
        monContainer.hidden = true
        tuesContainer.hidden = true
        wedContainer.hidden = true
        thursContainer.hidden = true
        friContainer.hidden = true
        satContainer.hidden = true
        sunContainer.hidden = false
    default:
        break;
    }
```

How can I select a certain segment from another view controller so that when I return to this View the container that I want is visible and the corresponding segment is selected?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be saving global state somewhere for any part of your application to access. Even something as simple as a shared object (singleton) or an object tied to `UIApplicationDelegate` will do fine here.

One option is to use the singleton method. A lot of people don't like to use singletons for various reasons but I think it's an easy illustration of a global value in this case. The point of a singleton is to keep an object around for the lifetime of the application. An alternative would be to tie this state to `UIApplicationDelegate`.

To implement the singleton (you can put this in its own file if you wish, I called it `UserState` but you can change that to whatever you want):

```
private let _UserStateSharedInstance = UserState()

class UserState  {
    class var sharedInstance : UserState {
        return _UserStateSharedInstance
    }
    var selectedDay = 0
}
```

In this view controller you can retrieve the selected day:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    dayPicker.selectedSegmentIndex = UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay
}

@IBAction func dayPickerControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay = sender.selectedSegmentIndex // You probably also want to set this here

    // Do your switching here
}
```

In your other view controller you can set your selected day:

```
@IBAction func dayPickerControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```

---

While we're at it, might I suggest an easier way to do this switching?

We might start out by combining each case into a simple logical statement to avoid having to repeat the list over and over again:

```
@IBAction func dayPickerControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let segmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

    monContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 0)
    tuesContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 1)
    wedContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 2)
    thursContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 3)
    friContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 4)
    satContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 5)
    sunContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 6)
}
```

Now it's becoming more obvious that this is just an array of views that we want to hide/show depending on an index. We might rewrite this with a loop:

```
var viewsToHide: [UIView]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewsToHide = [monContainer, tuesContainer, wedContainer, thursContainer, friContainer, satContainer, sunContainer]
}

@IBAction func dayPickerControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let segmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

    for (index, view) in enumerate(viewsToHide ?? []) {
        view.hidden = (segmentIndex != index)
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of worked.  I say kind of for the following reasons: 1)  UserState.sharedInstance().selectedDay produces an error, but if I remove the () the error gets fixed.  No biggie.  2)  The correct segment is being selected now, but the correct view is not showing.  for example, if I want the Wed segment selected showing and the corresponding Wed view visible, the segment is showing as selected but the view is not showing.  If I then click another segment then click back on Wed it will show the correct view, but it isn't loading that way.

Comment: PS - tried this both ways: the way I had it previously and the way you suggested - 
        monContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 0)
        tuesContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 1)
        wedContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 2)
        thursContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 3)
        friContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 4)
        satContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 5)
        sunContainer.hidden = (segmentIndex != 6)

Comment: Sorry about the extra parens, I copied that singleton code from somewhere and didn't realize they were using var instead of a method. You need to add `dayPicker.selectedSegmentIndex = UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay` to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` in any view controller that has the segmented control for it to populate correctly. I imagine you just added it to the view controller you were returning from.

Comment: Still can't get this to work.  The correct segment is selected but the correct container view is still not visible without rechecking as I mentioned above.  dayPicker.selectedSegmentIndex = UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay isn't able to be added to the container views because it is part of the main view controller.  I did a work around for this by creating a new variable but I'm still unable to get it to work correctly.

Comment: picker =  UserState.sharedInstance.selectedDay
        
        dayPicker.selectedSegmentIndex = picker